# calling LoaderManager in onItemSelectedListener in AdapterView inside Fragment

Tags: java, android

i'm trying to initiate LoaderManager on spinner item selected in FragmentActivity but have been getting error, i call the same loaderManager passing this as context outside onItemSelectedListener and it worked perfectly but unable to call it inside onItemSelectedListener.

```
cryptoSpinners.setOnItemSelectedListener (new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            selected = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
            loaderManager.restartLoader(1, null, this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

I'm getting the below error

> Wrong 3rd argument type. Found: 'android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener', required: 'android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks

Comment: `but have been getting error,`, what error?

Comment: Wrong 3rd argument type. Found: 'android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener', required: 'android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<java.lang.Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`loaderManager.restartLoader(1, null, this);`

`this` in the above code refers to the anonymous implementation object.

but you need to pass an implementation of `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks`, i'm guessing your containing activity implements `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks` and that's why you passed `this`, if that is so pass `YourActivity.this`